# Maximum entropy distribution with given mean, variance and skewness?

Tags: probability-distributions, entropy, maximum-principle

Is there a way to find the [maximum entropy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution) with certain values for the three first [moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)), when the support is the set of real numbers? Or, without loss of generality, with mean zero, unit variance and skewness $\gamma$? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the support $S=\mathbb{R}$, there is no maximum entropy distribution with mean $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, variance $\sigma^2\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and skewness $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$. You can always find distributions that satisfy those constraints, but the set of different entropies that they can take on is open, and therefore doesn't have a maximum value.

For $S=[-a, +a]$ and for some sufficiently large $a\in\mathbb{R}$, [there is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Continuous_case) a maximum entropy distribution $\mathcal{P}(a,\mu,\sigma^2,\gamma)$ with mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$ and skewness $\gamma$, and it will have a probability density function on the form $f(x) = Z^{-1}e^{\lambda_1 x^1 + \lambda_2 x^2 + \lambda_3 x^3}$. Assuming that $\gamma\neq 0$, this distribution will have a strictly smaller entropy than the maximum entropy distribution with the same mean and variance but with zero skewness, which is $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and for $a - |\mu| \gg \sigma$, $\mathcal{P}(a,\mu,\sigma^2,\gamma)$ will look practically like $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, with a small amount of its probability mass taken and pressed against one of the interval endpoints. And in the limit as $a\to\infty$, $\mathcal{P}(a,\mu,\sigma^2,\gamma)$ will approach $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and therefore its entropy will approach that of $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

A probability distribution with a small amount of its probability mass taken and moved far away from the distribution center in order to give rise to a skewness was not was I had in mind, though. (Bad distribution!) Considering the fact that even though the skewness of this distribution has the value that was specified, but higher order moments will approach either $\infty$ or $-\infty$ as $a\to\infty$, it becomes apparent that to get something that is more reasonable, some of the higher order moments need to be constrained as well. Constraining the kurtosis (the fourth standardized moment) to a maximum value makes the problem solvable when $S=\mathbb{R}$ and introduced an $x^4$ term with a negative coefficient in the exponent, which keeps the probability density function bounded and makes all higher order moments well defined as well.